How long has given package been deferred due to phasing?
When I run apt upgrade on my Ubuntu 24.04 (Noble Numbat) I see message

The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
file-roller

And it seems to me that this file-roller is phased for quite a long time, but I don't keep a record when it got installed/upgraded.
How to find out for how long it has been deferred?

You have records in /var/apt/log when the package was installed or upgraded, but that doesn't tell you how long the upgrade is deferred now. I don't think that there is a way to find out. Phasing will take longer if critical bugs are detected, this is probably the case here. Remind that phasing prevents receiving a buggy update for the majority of users. You shouldn't do anything about it, just be patient.

It is /var/log/dpkg.log Thanks.

I made a typo anyway, I meant var/log/apt/.

Please be aware that SECURITY updates are not phased.

The Phased Update tracker does track days.
Reminder that it is an internal dashboard meant for developer/team use.

Do not ping developers "Hey, did you forget about this? When will it be done?" They did not forget. Phased Update failures are a high priority, are also complex and sometimes subtle. The Ubuntu developers  will not compound the original problem by rushing.
Do not abuse the tracker with scripts or scrapers, lest it be closed from public observation.
Do not ask for access to the specific linked error or bug if your access is denied. A private bug contains personal or sensitive information. To get access, you must be an actively contributing member of the team with a record of trust.

